# Is there a way to preserve formatting for text pasted from Word into a Flex textarea?

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, ms-word, mxml

I've been experimenting with MXML- and spark-textarea (and richtexteditor)

I found that, when I copied some formatted texts like **Test** *tes1* from MS Word 2007 and paste them inside the Flash textarea, the formatting is gone (I only receive the plain texts).

But when I do the same to the Jwysiwyg (a jQuery WYSIWYG text editor), the formatting doesn't disappear.

Is there a way to make Flash textareas receive formatted text without destroying said formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MS Word use a html text method, so you can't.
You may continue to use jwysiwyg editor, or this AIR app :

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&marketplaceid=1&offeringid=10200